# Set text in a label

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flexbuilder

This should be super simple but I can't for the life of me seem to get it to just set the text of a label at run time. It throws "1120: Access of undefined property lbl_param"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               width="398" height="85" minWidth="398" minHeight="85">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Label id="lbl_param" x="19" y="10" width="105" height="29" text="Paramaters: "/>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            lbl_param.text = "test113";
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code to set the lbl_param.text should be in a method:   The only code in a script block you can run outside of a method is a class import or a variable definition.  This sample puts the code in a initialize event hander:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               width="398" height="85" minWidth="398" minHeight="85" initialize="init()">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Label id="lbl_param" x="19" y="10" width="105" height="29" text="Paramaters: "/>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
           public function init():void{
            lbl_param.text = "test113";
           }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script></s:Application>
```

Disclaimer: I wrote this code in the browser and it may not be "compiler" perfect.

Comment: Thanks so much, all my code seems to work perfect so long as I wrap them in functions. Your a life saver. I got really good with node.js and javascript and figured I could just pick up this language and run with it, nope, chuck testa.